# How can I programmatically remove a page from a PDF document on a Mac?

Tags: macos, pdf

I have a bunch of PDF documents and all of them contain a title page that I want to remove.

Is there a way to programmatically remove them?

Most of the PDF utilities I found can only combine documents but not remove pages. In the print dialog I can choose page 2 to  and then print to a file, but I can't find any way to access this function programmatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/).

To remove page 8:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-7 9-end output out.pdf
```

Comment: Btw, in case anyone else is also too lazy to figure out how to build pdftk (macport is still having problem with gcc42), here is a binary

http://fredericiana.com/2010/03/01/pdftk-1-41-for-mac-os-x-10-6/

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record: you can also use Ghostscript:

```
gs \
  -o removed-page-1-from-input.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dFirstPage=2 \
  /path/to/input.pdf
```

However, `pdftk` is the better tool for *that* job (and was already recommended to you).

Also, this Ghostscript commandline could change some of the properties in your input.pdf because it essentially *re-distills* it. This could be a desired change or not. To control individual aspects of this behavior (or to suppress some of them), a more complicated commandline with more parameters is required.

pdftk will re-use the original PDF objects for each page as-is.

---

#### Update

Ghostscript has the additional parameter of `-dLastPage` too. Together with `-dFirstPage` this allows for the extraction of page ranges.

The newest versions sport an new parameter, `-sPageList`. This could be used like this:

```
-sPageList="1, 5-10, 12-"
```

to extract pages 1, 5-10 and 12-last from the input document. However, I've not (yet) personally tested this new feature and I'm not sure how reliably it works.

For older versions of Ghostscript (as well as the most recent one), it should work to feed the same input PDF multiple times with different parameters to same GS call to extract non-contiguous page selections from a document. You could even combine pages from different documents this way:

```
gs \
  -o selected-pages.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite     \
  -dFirstPage=2         \
  -dLastPage=2          \
   in1.pdf              \
                        \
  -dFirstPage=10        \
  -dLastPage=15         \
   in1.pdf              \
                        \
  -dFirstPage=1         \
  -dLastPage=1          \
   in1.pdf              \
                        \
  -dFirstPage=4         \
  -dLastPage=6          \
   in2.pdf
```

---

***Caveats:*** Combining pages from different documents which use non-embedded fonts or identical font names but different encodings and/or different subsets (with identical fontname-prefixes) may lead to a faulty PDF in the result.

Comment: What if a PDF has 4 pages and I want to delete the 3rd page only? I guess this won't work then. The only other option would be to extract pages 1 till 2 and page 4 then glue them back. If it's GS which we are using.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: Newer Ghostscript versions support a new param: ***`-sPageList="1, 5-10, 12-"`*** -- should process pages 1, 5-10 and 12 to last page of input file. However, I never really tested it, so I don't know how reliable it works. For older version you could feed input PDF multiple times with different parameters to same GS call: ***`gs -o a.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 in.pdf -dFirstPage=5 -dLastPage=10 in.pdf -dFirstPage=12 in.pdf`*** to achieve the same result....

Comment: ... Of course, you could apply the same technique to process different input files with different page ranges into one output document.

Comment: I upvoted the comment which answered my specific question, but true, the main answer deserves one too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`-[PDFDocument removePageAtIndex:]` looks like it should make this possible.  By the way, Preview.app can remove a page, but it isn't scriptable, so that's not a programmatic solution.